# Ahsoka Novel: How did Ahsoka know the identity of this person?

Tags: star-wars, ahsoka-tano

In the new canon novel *Ahsoka*, it is revealed that

> Ahsoka is aware that Emperor Palpatine is Lord Sidious.

However, it does not seem to discuss *how* she came to know this information.

So is there any other canon material that reveals how she came to know? Or was she able to deduce the truth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It’s not because Anakin told her

Ahsoka definitely knows that Palpatine is a Sith Lord. What’s more, she seems to know that he is extremely powerful, which suggests she might have known that he was Darth Sidious, the Sith Lord that Jedi knew had orchestrated the war:

> The shadow was almost certainly one of the dark side’s creatures.
>   Ahsoka had no idea what sort of thing it might be, but whatever it was
>   couldn’t be that powerful, because it hadn’t been able to track down
>   Hedala. That ruled out Palpatine himself, not that the Emperor could
>   just show up on a planet without causing a great deal of alarm.
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

**The most obvious possibility would seem to be that Anakin told her.**  However, we know that as of the last time Anakin saw her, he was not aware of Palpatine’s true identity. From the *Rebels* episode "Shroud of Darkness":

> AHSOKA: The last time I saw him, he was rushing off to save the Chancellor.
>   Then everything changed. The war ended and the Jedi were accused of
>   treason. One by one, they were hunted down. By the Inquisitors.

This is a bit ambiguous, but it [refers](http://makingstarwars.net/2016/03/dave-filoni-reveals-details-on-the-final-arc-of-star-wars-the-clone-wars/) to Anakin going off to save Palpatine from his "kidnapping" by General Grievous:

> So she was caught up in that, and basically she says point, “The last
>   time I saw Anakin, he was rushing off to save the Chancellor.” She was
>   actually planning with Obi Wan and Anakin the capture and attack that
>   would get them Maul, because she had figured out where he was towards
>   the end of the Clone War. But before they can go through with this
>   plan together, **Obi Wan and at one Anakin get called away to Coruscant
>   to save the Chancellor**, which leaves her with Rex – and some other
>   exciting characters – to basically go and deal with Darth Maul, once
>   and for all. That’s kind of a good brief of what that was about.

So Anakin could not have told her that Palpatine was a Sith Lord. To  the best of my knowledge, she had no contact with Yoda or Obi-Wan, the other two people who knew Palpatine’s true identity.

### She probably deduced it

For someone inclined to think so, and with the knowledge that the surviving Jedi had, there was *abundant* reason to believe that Palpatine was Sith.

As mentioned previously, the Jedi knew that a Sith Lord called Sidious was behind everything, from the time of *Attack of the Clones*:

> COUNT DOOKU: The truth. What if I told you that the Republic was now
>   under the control of the Dark Lords of the Sith?
>
> OBI-WAN: No, that’s not possible. The Jedi would be aware of it.
>
> COUNT DOOKU: The dark side of the Force has clouded their vision, my
>   friend. Hundreds of Senators are now under the influence of a Sith
>   Lord called Darth Sidious.

1. The clones turned on all the Jedi in the galaxy, after receiving an order that could only have come from the supreme commander of the Grand Army of the Republic: Palpatine. Who but the shadowy Sith Lord Sidious would have wanted to kill all the Jedi? What’s more, Ahsoka had Rex with her, so she knew the source of the command (as Rex would have guessed): the chips.

   > The Jedi were gone, but what happened to the clones was almost worse.
   >   Their identities, their free will, removed with a simple voice command
   >   and the activation of a chip.
   >
   > <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>
2. Palpatine declared himself Emperor, and the war ended quickly and suspiciously. This coincided with the fall of the Jedi Order. Who would have wanted this?  Sidious. Sidious would have ended up in the position of greatest power once he won. It’s what Sith do—think Dooku as head of the Separatists, or Maul setting himself up as dictator of Mandalore.
3. Anakin went to save the Chancellor and didn’t come back. Ahsoka would naturally suspect betrayal, by the most likely suspect: Chancellor Palpatine.
4. Ahsoka has heard that Palpatine is using Sith or other dark side entities as his servants:

   > It also ruled out whatever Palpatine was using to track down surviving
   >   Jedi. Ahsoka had heard rumors of a dark lord who served the Emperor,
   >   but nothing confirmable.
   >
   > <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

   If darksiders are serving the Emperor, it’s a *strong* sign that he’s a Sith Lord.

   This is basically the same reasoning that Palpatine himself suspecting Grand Moff Tarkin of using:

   > Tarkin may also have determined that Vader was a Sith. If so, it
   >   followed that he accepted that Sidious was Vader’s dark side Master.
   >
   > <sub>*Tarkin*</sub>

Comment: Good reasoning. Are you sure that when Anakin went to go save the Chancellor wasn't actually when they "rescued" him from Dooku? That's how I interpreted it at first. I recall the book mentioning that both Anakin and Obi wan were originally planning to help with Mandalore and that they both left to go save the Chancellor, which would imply the Dooku rescue. Also, Since the novel is new, would you consider putting the quotes in spoiler tags for now?

Comment: @DBPriGuy - I thought of that possibility, but the whole thing with the clones and Order 66 seems to happen too soon afterward for that to be the case. I also checked, and it did not look like Obi-Wan was going to help with Mandalore. Also, since your question begins with “Ahsoka novel,” I think that should be sufficient warning.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the timeline feels too tight. But it's possible that the scene of Anakin giving Ahsoka her lightsabers occurs before the Siege of Mandalore, and given the name 'siege', it's entirely possible that the campaign to take the planet spanned the entire time of RotS. Also, what's the setting of the scene? Is this on Coruscant or Mandalore? If on Mandalore, that seems to have continuity difficulties with the movie

Comment: @DBPriGuy - The scene is definitely not on Mandalore. She’s remembering it, within the context of the flashback. Although, hang on a moment.

Comment: @DBPriGuy - Basically, Anakin gave Ahsoka her lightsabers and some clone troopers, and she went off to confront Maul. Meanwhile, he went to save Palpatine. Then all the events of RotS and Order 66 went down, and her troopers attacked Ahsoka. I think.

Comment: @DBPriGuy - Although the wiki seems to think that this is referring to the events you mentioned, Palpatine’s abduction. Let me look into this further.

Comment: Let’s see then....